# Creating Bottom Border on Bootstrap 3 Grid Columns w/ Gutter

Tags: css

I have been trying to set up a grid using bootstrap 3 where all the columns will have the same height even with different content sizes - which I have accomplished using flexbox.  But now I am trying to add a solid border to the bottom of each item in the grid and I just can't get it to work (I want a border on the bottom, with a gutter between grid elements).

I can do it easily on the top like: https://codepen.io/Wafflenaut/pen/dvzWzb

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="display:flex; flex-flow: row wrap;">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" >
        <div style="border-top:5px solid; border-top-color:#df5400;">
```

But when I try it on the buttom I get a result like: http://codepen.io/Wafflenaut/pen/perPWL

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="display:flex; flex-flow: row wrap;">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" >
        <div style="border-bottom:5px solid; border-bottom-color:#df5400;">
```

If I try it directly on the column divs I get a solid bar.  So - I basically need to either get a gutter functioning between columns or to get a nested div to go full height.  I’ve tried a number of solutions (various padding tricks, vh, etc.), which tend to either not work or to break responsiveness.

And the kicker - this is within a CMS which I lack any access to the css or js files - so everything I do has to be workable inline from within a section of the html body.

Any suggestions for avenues of attack?

Comment: is setting an absolute  height an option?

Comment: for each div in your column, set 100% height. .col-xs-12.col-sm-4>div {
  height: 100%;
}. like @happymacarts suggested.

Comment: also you could create custom classes instead of using all the inline styles (even with a cms) then if you can't include a seperate css file at least you could include all your styles in a `<style>` block at the top of the doc. Future you will appreciate it when he comes to edit this later

Comment: [Here](http://codepen.io/happymacarts/pen/jBLLxr) is my above solution if you want to see it. I didn't post as an answer because @ovokuru beat me to it but thought the class part may be useful

Comment: Unfortunately, no access to the header - I thought style tags needed to be in the header?  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `display: flex` to the div with `class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"`

[codepen](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/yMoXvm)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="display:flex; flex-flow: row wrap;">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" style="display:flex;">
      <div style="border-bottom:5px solid; border-bottom-color:#df5400;">
        <p>replace me</p>
        <h2>Item 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eu nisi fermentum, mollis massa quis, scelerisque elit. Donec nec viverra.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" style="display:flex;">
      <div style="border-bottom:5px solid; border-bottom-color:#df5400;">
        <h2>Item 2</h2>
        <p>replace me</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris laoreet lectus est. Fusce lobortis, velit sed finibus volutpat, magna nibh porttitor justo, at ornare quam nunc eu nulla. Fusce lacinia.</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" style="display:flex;">
      <div style="border-bottom:5px solid; border-bottom-color:#df5400;">
        <p>replace me</p>
        <h2>Item 3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eu nisi fermentum, mollis massa quis, scelerisque elit. Donec nec viverra.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" style="display:flex;">
      <div style="border-bottom:5px solid; border-bottom-color:#df5400;">
        <h2>Item 4</h2>
        <p>replace me</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eu nisi fermentum, mollis massa quis, scelerisque elit. Donec nec viverra.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" style="display:flex;">
      <div style="border-bottom:5px solid; border-bottom-color:#df5400;">
        <h2>Item 5</h2>
        <p>replace me</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eu nisi fermentum, mollis massa quis, scelerisque elit. Donec nec viverra.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" style="display:flex;">
      <div style="border-bottom:5px solid; border-bottom-color:#df5400;">
        <p>replace me</p>
        <h2>Item 6</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris laoreet lectus est. Fusce lobortis, velit sed finibus volutpat, magna nibh porttitor justo, at ornare quam nunc eu nulla. Fusce lacinia.</p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly!  I guess I need to delve deeper into flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a height of 100% to each of the inline styles.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row" style="display:flex; flex-flow: row wrap;">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" >
          <div style="border-bottom:5px solid; border-bottom-color:#df5400; height: 100%">
```

Comment: This doesn't work - it ends up doing the same thing as my second example (uneven placement of the border depending on size of content in the div)

Comment: Possible issue with Bootstrap 4 vs Bootstrap 3?